# While connecting to Mongodb an error rises

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the code that I wrote in my script page

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, function(err){
  if(!err){console.log("Connected to Database");}
  else{console.log(err);}
});

const userSchema = {
  email: String,
  password: String
};

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

//////////////////error displays in cmd////////////////////

```
reason:TopologyDescription {

            type: 'Single',
            setName: null,
            maxSetVersion: null,
            maxElectionId: null,
            servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
            stale: false,
            compatible: true,
            compatibilityError: null,
            logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
            heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
            localThresholdMS: 15,
            commonWireVersion: null
          }
        }
```

And I started my localhost in 2000 port.

When I try to connect via Robo 3T the error raises as
[image: Error Image]

Comment: "target machine actively refused it" means the operating system rejected the connection because either nothing is listening on that port, or that port is blocked by a firewall rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of problem I tried all commands available in stack overflow and in some other websites and I finally came up with a solution that you have to reinstall `mongodb` properly and using CMD remove all the folders related to `mongodb` and `mongoose` by following command `npm uninstall mongodb --force` and `npm uninstall mongoose --force` and then restart your server and you all set to go.
Don't forget to remove and reinstall all files related to `mongo` in your project folder too.